# Dplyr Mutate Syntax

Tags: r, function, dplyr, syntax, variable-assignment

```
girders <- mutate(materials.split[[girder.Option]], bridge.Q = girders.V, interventions = interventions.girders)
```

Hello people. I want to ask about mutate function in Dplyr for R. When I see the syntax of mutate, I generally see only two parts in the mutate function. But I have an example above. There are three parts. What does it exactly mean this line? What does the coder want to do there? For example, mutate creates new columns in a table. But what does it mean here girders <- mutate ? is "girders" the new name of the new column which is created? Could you explain this?

Comment: The first part is the data, `materials.split[[girder.Option]]` (i believe you have a list and it is extracting a list component i.e. data.frame/tibble, the second and third, ...., etc are the columns created/updated.  Here, you are creating duplicate columns instead of renaming the original column.  If you need to rename use `rename` or `rename_with`

Comment: If you have doubts regarding the usage, check the help i.e. `?mutate` `mutate(
  .data,
  ...,
  .keep = c("all", "used", "unused", "none"),
  .before = NULL,
  .after = NULL
)`

Comment: This is a question about a very essential part of the R syntax; it has nothing to do with ‘dplyr’, or with `mutate`. You urgently need to read an introduction into R! You cannot use the language without first learning the basics.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right. I am around the beginner level. but I am trying to learn right now. below I wrote my problem as an answer. I could not make R find bridge.Q. There is a similar tutorial but it does not mention any problem like this. So I could not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters in dplyr functions may vary depending upon the context. The idea of the pipeline in dplyr is to pass the result of the previous function as the first (data) parameter to the next function (dplyr verb). So you can substitute the provided line of code with the following dplyr equivalent:

```
girders <-  materials.split[[girder.Option]] %>%
 mutate(bridge.Q = girders.V, interventions = interventions.girders)
```

`materials.split[[girder.Option]]` is set then after `%>%` passed as the first parameter of `mutate`. If you add another `%>%` operator the resulting dataset will be passed to the following verb and so on. In this case the function will not require setting the first dataset parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`<-` is the assignment operator in R. `x <- y` means we are assigning the right-hand side of the operation (aka, 'y') to a new (or overriden) variable `x` . It has nothing to do with dplyr.

Try a few examples to understand it:

```
a <- 5+6
a
[1] 11

#or to illustrate with dplyr

library(dplyr)

tiny_iris <- iris %>%
    select(1:2) %>%
    slice(1:2)

tiny_iris
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1          5.1         3.5
2          4.9         3.0
```